# Issue translating "next"-button in datatable due to interference with "next"-statement

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am running a Shiny app that shows a datatable (dt), and I am trying to translate all of the buttons to make a German, French and Italian version of it.

I am inserting the dt as follows:

```
langIdx = 2 # English is 1, German 2, French 3, Italian 4

DT::datatable(thisDat, options = list(pageLength = 10, 
                                      columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets="_all")),
                                      language = list(search = searchTransl[langIdx],
                                                      lengthMenu = showEntrTransl[langIdx],
                                                      info = showEntrTransl2[langIdx],
                                                      paginate = list(
                                                          previous = c("Previous","Vorherige","Précédente",
                                                                       "Precedente")[langIdx],
                                                          next = c("Next", "Nächste", "Prochaine", "Prossima")
                                                      ))))
```

All other translations (search, lengthMenu, info, paginate, previous) work, and "next" should work the same way as "previous", but there is an error because "next" is a statement in R. How else can I call this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use quotes :

```
list("next" = "Next")
```

Or special quotes (Alt + 7) :

```
list(`next` = "Next")
```

You can also use syntax available here : https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/German.json, e.g. :

```
DT::datatable(iris, options = list(language = list(
  oPaginate = list(sNext = "Nächste")
)))
```

Or directly use URL:

```
DT::datatable(iris, options = list(
  language = list(
    url = "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.20/i18n/German.json"
  )
))
```